# When changing languages dynamically should the HTML lang attribute be updated?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, lang

I have a single-page website that loads an AngularJS application that supports different languages.

All the views for the website are rendered in the browser via JavaScript after the HTML has been loaded from the server.

I understand the value of setting a correct language attribute for `<html lang="en">` when Google indexes the static pages.

I am wondering if I need to update this language attribute when AngularJS dynamically changes languages. For example; The user can select from a dropdown which language the interface is shown as.

When the language changes there is no re-loading from the server. So the last setting `<html lang="en">` will persist.

Is there any reason that I should update this attribute dynamically when the language changes?

**EDIT:** This is not a question about google or web crawlers. I'm wondering if this attribute is used by the web browser in anyway.

Comment: From what i gather from google's own webmaster tools blog at http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2010/03/working-with-multilingual-websites.html google is terrible with automated translations. The indexer/crawler does not interpret javascript, so i doubt it would be of any use doing that client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Screen readers use this attribute. But you also have to test that screen readers would consider correctly a dynamic change in this attribute.

Comment: More correctly, screen readers *may* use this attribute. So it is better to omit it completely than to have it set to a wrong value. Even better, it should be set to a value that corresponds to the actual value.

Comment: Screen readers... yes that is a great example of what I was worried about.

Comment: More exactly, you have to use this attribute. WCAG says it. I obey. Screen readers like Jaws can try to guess, or use the default language but it's not a good reason to avoid its use.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't even care what the language attribute is set to.

> Google uses only the visible content of your page to determine its language. We don’t use any code-level language information such as lang attributes. You can help Google determine the language correctly by using a single language for content and navigation on each page, and by avoiding side-by-side translations. [...]

So changing that attribute wouldn't make any difference. You can read more about it here: [Multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en#1)

Comment: This is true and relevant, but does not actually answer the question asked.